# replaced recessed light w/ceiling fan, it seems I have to turn on at least one light to complete circuit

Tags: ceiling-fan

I replaced recessed can light w/ceiling fan, works great, if I want a recessed light on while ceiling fan is on. I do not. I need at least one working bulb in a socket it appears to complete circuit. Is there an easy way to complete circuit w/out having to use a bulb?  there are 6 recessed lights on the circuit, I replaced one w/ceiling fan. All work off of one switch, w/a dimmer.

Comment: You should  hire an electrician. I'm all in favor of DIY electric work by non-electricians (I'm not an electrician) who pay attention to what they are doing and figure out how to do it correctly. When folks dive in and do something illogical, (and this qualifies) I think it's a whole lot safer for them and the rest of their family if they stop, admit being in over their heads, and get a pro to sort it out before they do some real damage.

Answer (score 1):

If the recessed light you replaced turned on/off with the switch, then the ceiling fan is also going to turn on/off with the switch. If removing a bulb from the socket causes the fan to turn off, you've done something seriously wrong.

You should contact an Electrician to install the fan properly.